# Any way that the jquery/javascript can detected the page is run from WPF?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way that the jQuery/javascript can detected that it is running in [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)?

I created a web page that runs in WPF in window. Can jquery/javascript detect the page is running in WPF?